# HTML routes rendered only through localhost

Tags: angularjs

I found a basic example on youtube that demonstrates routes through angular. When I load the set of files from this screen http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zogrnQjHZAM it does not work.

I can see the index.html, but the partials do not render. I think it is because I am not serving these files through a server. If that is the case, how is angular different? I thought static files can be seen without them being served.

index.html -

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="website">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Website</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/website.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- top -->
<header id="header">
    <h1 id="logo"><a href="#/home"></a></h1>

    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#/home" class="btn">Home</a>
        <a href="#/about" class="btn">About</a>
        <a href="#/experiments" class="btn">Experiments</a>
    </div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</header>
<!-- //top -->
<div class="shadow"></div>

<div id="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/website.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Router --

```
angular.module('website', []).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/about', {templateUrl: 'partials/about.html', controller: 'AboutCtrl'}).
            when('/experiments', {templateUrl: 'partials/experiments.html', controller: 'ExperimentsCtrl'}).
            when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'}).
            otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
    })
    .controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope', 'StateService', function ($scope, StateService) {
        $scope.title = 'About Page';
        $scope.body = 'This is the about page body';

        $scope.message = StateService.getMessage();

        $scope.updateMessage = function (m) {
            StateService.setMessage(m);
        };
    }])
    .controller('ExperimentsCtrl', ['$scope', 'StateService', function ($scope, StateService) {
        $scope.title = 'Experiments Page';
        $scope.body = 'This is the about experiments body';

        $scope.message = StateService.getMessage();

        $scope.updateMessage = function (m) {
            StateService.setMessage(m);
        };
    }])
    .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'StateService', function ($scope, StateService) {
        $scope.title = 'Home Page';
        $scope.body = 'This is the about home body';

        $scope.message = StateService.getMessage();

        $scope.updateMessage = function (m) {
            StateService.setMessage(m);
        };
    }])
    .factory('StateService', function () {
        var message = 'Hello Message';
        var getMessage = function() {
            return message;
        };
        var setMessage = function(m) {
            message = m;
        };

        return {
            getMessage: getMessage,
            setMessage: setMessage
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to add ngRoute module in your module:

```
angular.module('website', [ngRoute]).
    config(function ($routeProvider) ...
```

You also have to include the angular-route js file. Which is not bundled with angularjs now..

and this will work

Comment: this works on my localhost server. I'm confused on why

Comment: It works on my web server, but I'm confused on why it doesnt load when I just launch the index.html in a separate folder, without calling localhost.. from my browser.

Comment: not i am getting what exactly is not working here. can you please explain in slightly more detail..  ?